# SOLR - Heap Space - Out of memory error when trying to reindex

Tags: solr

I have approx 17 million records that I need to load into SOLR. The data I have is pipe separated and the max length will be 220 characters.

The data is in the format:

```
LEVEL 1|SHOP 1|STREET NUMBER|STREET NAME|STREET TYPE|NORTH|CITY NAME|STATE|ZIPCODE|BUILDING NAME|ADDRESS CODE
```

The issue I am facing is that if I don't include the last field, ADDRESS CODE and index the data, it works fine.

With the ADDRESS CODE field included, I get the error:

```
2023-08-18 13:25:30.353 ERROR (searcherExecutor-35-thread-1) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrCore null:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.Packed64.<init>(Packed64.java:73)
at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.PackedInts.getMutable(PackedInts.java:974)
at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.PackedInts.getMutable(PackedInts.java:941)
at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.GrowableWriter.<init>(GrowableWriter.java:46)
at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.PagedGrowableWriter.newMutable(PagedGrowableWriter.java:56)
at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.AbstractPagedMutable.fillPages(AbstractPagedMutable.java:57)
at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.PagedGrowableWriter.<init>(PagedGrowableWriter.java:50)
at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.PagedGrowableWriter.<init>(PagedGrowableWriter.java:43)
at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.NodeHash.rehash(NodeHash.java:177)
at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.NodeHash.add(NodeHash.java:146)
at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.Builder.compileNode(Builder.java:253)
at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.Builder.freezeTail(Builder.java:349)
at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.Builder.add(Builder.java:453)
at org.apache.lucene.search.suggest.analyzing.AnalyzingSuggester.build(AnalyzingSuggester.java:573)
at org.apache.lucene.search.suggest.Lookup.build(Lookup.java:190)
at org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.SolrSuggester.build(SolrSuggester.java:182)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SuggestComponent$SuggesterListener.buildSuggesterIndex(SuggestComponent.java:548)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SuggestComponent$SuggesterListener.newSearcher(SuggestComponent.java:533)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.lambda$getSearcher$17(SolrCore.java:2416)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore$$Lambda$814/0x000000080124ef68.call(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:218)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$$Lambda$235/0x0000000800ed7700.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I have tried starting solr as :

```
solr start -p <port> -m 8g
```

I have also tried to modify solr.cmd, by setting:

```
Xms4g -Xmx8g
```

but with the extra field in place, I always get the error. Is there something, I am missing?